# Fill dataset record with string from array

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, dataset

So I created a Dataset that is not bind to any database. Within this dataset I have a table named `Customer` with it's own column defined. Now I want to populate this table with strings that was retrieved from a text file. I don't know how to accomplish this. So basically I want to populate the dataset table with those string and use this dataset to populate or to be datasource of my crystal report. Any idea how to do this? Below is a screenshot of my dataset

[image]

Below is what I was thinking not sure if it's possible

```
DataSet ds = new Dataset1(); // DataSet1 is the name of the dataset I added
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Customer");
dt.fill("mother_name", "String 1");
dt.fill("beneficial_name", "String 2");
ds.Table(dt);
```

Note: Above code is not the actual code but what I was thinking of achieving. It's basically adding a row/record in the datatable and assign that datatable to my table in my dataset then using that dataset to be the datasource of my crystalreport

Comment: @SᴇM yes almost but how do I assign the new Datatable into my Dataset1?

Comment: `ds.Tables.Add(dt);`